# Is it possible to follow http redirect in AWS APIGateway ? If yes, how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-api-gateway, aws-api-gateway-v2

Say I have 2 classes of uri such as `/v1/api/*` and `/v2/api/*`. If a certain `/v1/api/*` url returns a 302 with location header pointed to `/v2/api/*`, I want AWS APIGateway to follow the redirect instead of the conventional redirection follow up by the browser.

Is it possible to do this in APIGateway ?
If yes, how and which integration to use ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That would require API Gateway to make a second API call to your backend, and I don't think that's possible.